# The best way to expose variable from function in python?

Tags: python

I have an inherit function in class, that defined as not return value.
I call the function from other class, and I need to get value from the function.
I don't create the class object, but call to other function that do it and run my function. so I can't to create get function to the variable.(I have not the class object)
I tried to pass a list in the class init, and append to this, but I understand this not good way.
What is the good way?
(for example, way to pass simple variable as a pointer)
Thanks!

Code for example:

```
class basic_class(object):
    def __init__(self, ret_list: list=[]):
        self.ret_list = ret_list

    def set_hello_to_ret_list(self):
        ret_val = 'hello'
        self.ret_list.append(ret_val)
        

class runner:
    def run(self, list_: list):
        basic = basic_class(ret_list=list_)
        basic.set_hello_to_ret_list()
        

class by_class:
    def get_hello(self):
        hello_list = []
        runner().run(hello_list)
        print(hello_list)
        
by_class().get_hello()
```

for example, I want to get the 'hello' string, so I pass a list to the class, so I can use it as a pointer.

Comment: It sounds a lot like you're doing something outside of what this particular inherited function is supposed to do, and should define a new function (one that returns a value).  But I'd need to see some actual code to know whether there's a good case for overloading this particular function for this particular purpose.

Comment: Can you show the code you're working with? Otherwise answers might not reflect the problem you're having

Comment: Why can't `runner.run` just return `"hello"` so you can do `print(runner.run())` in `get_hello`?  Your original question said something about inheritance, but there's no inheritance here, and even if there was I don't understand why `run()` wouldn't be able to return a value.  You're not using any kind of typechecking anyway so there's nothing stopping you from having an overridden function return a different type of value.

Comment: Its not the original code (the original is very long).
In my code the run() function is inherit and I can't return value/